# Update a column from another database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases oldBD and newDB
both have the same structure but different content. The new database is missing data  and I want to update or insert a column.

What I want is, to take all the information from a column "cache_default_attribute" in the table "ps_product" from the oldDB,
and add all the information to the newDB. In the newDB, all the values of "cache_default_attribute" is 0 
There are about 500 rows

Comment: I don't see a question. What is the problem? Which part of the manual isn't clear?

Comment: What have you tried? What are the keys in the two tables (so you can find the corresponding rows)?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE newDB.ps_product AS new
JOIN oldDB.ps_product AS old
SET new.cache_default_attribute = old.cache_default_attribute
WHERE new.id = old.id
```

This assumes there's an `id` column in the table that identifies the rows. Replace that with the actual primary key.